# Controlling Firefox from C/C++

Tags: c++, firefox-addon

I'm thinking of creating an application that can use Firefox as a download manager. Is there any way to control Firefox (add downloads, start/stop downloads, etc) from an external program in C/C++?

If that is not possible, then perhaps an extension that can do that? If an extension is the only way, then how do I communicate with the extension from outside of Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting with a solution, not a problem. The easier idea is to use XulRunner, the platform on which FireFox is built. You'd effectively implement your own application as a XulRunner plugin and use Necko (the network layer of XulRunner and FireFox) from there.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I suggest that you familiarize yourself with [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/)

As far as I understand, most Mozilla platform functions are available through a cross language API known as [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_API_Reference). There's also a [plugin API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins) but it's primary aim is to visualize stuff (used by Flash, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Gecko API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Home_Page). It allows third party developers to use the same technology as found in Mozilla.

For downloading files no need to use Firefox. Consider using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at wget.